# Constructing an NFA accepted by a grammar

Tags: formal-languages, automata

Contruct an NFA of the language accepted by the grammar below.

$$G=(\{S,A,B\}, \{a,b,c\},S,P)$$

$P: S\rightarrow abaS\ \ | \ cA\\
    \ \ \ \ \ \ A\rightarrow bA\ \ | \ cB \ \ | \ aa\\
    \ \ \ \ \ \ B\rightarrow bB \ \ | \ cA \ \ | \ bb$

No need to draw the NFA. My confusion is how to draw $S \rightarrow$ $abaS$. Is it just drawn out like $\rightarrow (q_0) \rightarrow a \rightarrow (q_1) \rightarrow b \rightarrow (q_2) \rightarrow a \rightarrow (q_3)$? I don't think that it is but I can't figure out how else to do it.

Also, when it says $A\rightarrow bA\ \ | \ cB \ \ | \ aa$, $\ $does the $aa$ represent a final state? If it does than does this NFA have two final states?

Comment: You are correct with the regard to the first question, and yes, the NFA can have two accepting states (the adjective _final_ is kind of misleading).

Comment: Ok thanks, so would $q_3$ be considered $S$?

Comment: I recommend JFLAP.

Comment: @GiBiT09 The $S$ is represented by $q_0$. Try transforming the grammar into one, where you have at most one terminal in each branch, e.g. $S_0 \to aS_1 \mid cA$, and then $S_1 \to bS_2$ and $S_2 \to aS_0$. Almost nothing changes, but it is easier for drawing an automaton.

Comment: Ooooo I see, thank you. Helped a lot.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516833/nfa-from-grammar-productions) from someone else working on the same exercise and my answer.